# Saving a Disabled field

Tags: cakephp

In my edit.ctp I have a select box which I don't need the user to change. So I put `array(disabled=>true)`. But this field is not coming when

`pr($this->data);` and showing an error while saving.

What options are there to solve this issue.

Comment: disabled fields do not get posted, you could use hidden field for passing to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the field **readonly** so that user cant change it , or use some hidden field to post the data that you want, or you could use some css, like **visibility:hidden**, so that user dont see it but it'll be posted.

```
echo this->Form->input('patient_id',array('type'=>'hidden'));
```

You can use some other name for the input and check in controller, or you could completely remove the select element from the view**strong text** (since, its not needed as user dont need to change it)

Comment: echo  this->Form->input('patient_id',array('type'=>'hidden'));                echo $this->Form->input('patient_id',array('disabled'=>'true'));When I code like above this also not posting patient_id.

Comment: If you use hidden fields, users can still easily edit them! Make sure you use some sort of form tampering protection to prevent this (see: SecurityComponent).

Comment: But when making the field readonly. All options in the select box still changeable to the user. How to make it solve?.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the value of the data you can edit it at the controller.

`$this->request->data['ModelName']['fieldName'] = value;`

**UPDATE**

Edit it like
`echo $this->Form->input('patient_id',array('type'=>'select', 'readonly' => 'readonly'));`

Comment: It displayed as read only. But user still able to select from the options.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Showing the information and saving it as is. thanks.